# Is it possible to add CTAN directory as a software source to the packet manager muon?

Tags: latex, muon-package-manager

I am using `muon` as a packet manager with Kubuntu. Normally everything works just fine, but I have some difficulties with `LaTex` packages. `muon` does not seem to find the latest versions.

[On CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/) there is a version from June 2013, while `muon` tells me that my version from 2012 is up to date.

I could install it manually, of course; but it is not that practical since I use LaTex a lot and would like to have all updates as soon as possible.

I noticed that it is possible to add new repositories to `muon`, and I considered adding the whole CTAN directory to the `muon` sources. But I do not know if that is necessary or even possible, plus I don't really understand the menu for adding repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. CTAN is not an Ubuntu package repository. If you always want the latest TeX packages, deinstall the Ubuntu TeXLive packages and instead install vanilla TeXLive.